# JAVA_HOME is not valid?

Tags: openjdk

I'm really hoping someone can help me to fix the issue I'm having and would be extremely grateful for anyone to offer a solution to this issue. …

When I try and launch OpenDaylight, I get the following error:
karaf: JAVA_HOME is not valid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Comment: So is it valid? Please add output of `ls -lah /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 2):

When you install the openjdk JRE or JDK, I don't think, a JAVA_HOME  environment variable is created for you.

You have two options, you can setup JAVA_HOME in the script that launches OpenDaylight. I have never used OpenDaylight so, I am not sure if such a script exists.

Secondly, you can take a look at the `.bashrc` of the id with which OpenDayLight is launching and set JAVA_HOME in this file.

On a related note, do you know if you have a JRE or a JDK? If you have a JDK, you won't see a jre in the path, it will read as, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get JAVA_HOME from Terminal by

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

Generally java home value should be set as

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

and Update PATH variable as

`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: after update PATH  ,Error : la commande n'a pas pu être trouvée car << /usr/bin>> n'est pas incluse dans la variable d'environnement PATH

Comment: Sorry for the issue. I have updated the solution. Try after rebooting as your PATH variable has been reset

Comment: error: karaf: JAVA_HOME is not valid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

Comment: don't put jre at the end. set till `amd64`